# How to fix no sound with skype on linux?

Tags: skype

I am using a Webcam C310 Analog Mono. I can visually see others on Skype and I can hear others on Skype, but nobody on Skype can hear me.

Any suggestions to find the problem?

Comment: Check skype's audio settings. Make sure you're using the right devices and maybe add the available options to your question.